# Azure - Container Instances vs App Service

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service, azure-container-service

I have a monorepo that contains an API, React app and a worker.

Initially I thought I'd just use AppService and deploy the code however that appears to be much more complicated as situation doesn't just have a simple `npm run index.js`, but has the 3 services I mentioned above in different places.

Anyhow, I've decided containerising in Docker may be an easier approach.

But I'm not sure, what's the difference between deploying to Azure's App Service and the Container Instance?

Thanks.

p.s. I'm assuming my approach above seems valid. Please let me know if there is an easier way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are quite a few benefits when running on App Services - especially when it is a web app:. Just to name a few

- (automatic or manual) Scaling to multiple instances
- SSL termination with built-in certs
- Easy app setting configuration
- IP restriction support
- Easy Auth - and other authentication providers built-in support